# Azure pricing scheme

Tags: cloud, azure

I want to deploy an app to Azure by using free trial. I read the (almost) whole Terms of Agreement for Azure.

If I use Azure free trial and use it without exceeding the limit defined in agreement than will I need to pay some other service charges or any other cost?

Furthermore I will be using SQL Server 2008,  .Net 4.0 and SQL Reporting Services.

So are there any charges for those or it is free?

Comment: I've done the trial and have not been billed. Currently I'm still using the 10 free websites offer without being charged (the only catch is you don't get your own URL). I've written a [blog post](http://www.infotopie.nl/blog/the-cloud/web-app) reflecting my experience with it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about self-hosted web applications.

Answer (score 3):

This is what it says on the homepage (for 90 days free trial)

> Quickly build, deploy & manage applications.
>   Use any operating system, language or tool.
>   No obligation, totally free.

**Use any language or tool** so I think you can use any languages and tools (SQL server 2008, .NET etc.) without paying any charges (at least during the trial period). They have more information about what they will be providing in the free trial on this page http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/

No, you don't need to pay anything till you are using the free trial. So don't worry and just try the free trial, if your trial period expires or you exceed the limits you will be prompted to choose a plan to continue using Azure.